# Trying to close alert alert dialog programmatically

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to do something simple and this was asked many times before in many variants but I couldn't manage to do it in my case..

I'm trying to do this scenario:

[image]

I have a popup alert dialog window (of some item) which has a delete button in it, and if you press the delete button it will popup another alert dialog of "are you sure you want to delete" with yes/no buttons.

If you press the yes it will delete the item and then I want both of the dialogs to be closed.

the yes/no dialog is closed by itself because I pressed the button, but the item dialog is not closed and I can't make it closed any how..

Here is my code:

```
private void popupItem(final int item_id) {

        //setup popup window
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Holo_Light_ButtonBar_AlertDialog));

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_popup_item_alert, null);

        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.edit_item));

        final AlertDialog item_alert = builder.create();


        //setup delete button
        final ImageButton deleteImageButton = (ImageButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.template_popup_item_delete);
        deleteImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickDeleteItem(item_id, item_alert);
            }
        });


        builder.show();

    }
```

and here is the delete function:

```
private void clickDeleteItem(final int item_id, final AlertDialog item_alert) {
        // create (another) popup delete for "are you sure? yes/no"
        AlertDialog.Builder alert_yesno = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        alert_yesno.setTitle(getString(R.string.want_to_remove));

        alert_yesno.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                // ... deleting the item(id)..

                dialog.dismiss(); // close yes/on dialog (redundant - it is closed by itself anyway)
                item_alert.dismiss(); // close the previous popup dialog //~~ NOT WORKING!

            }
        });

        alert_yesno.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
            }
        });

        alert_yesno.show();
    }
```

So as you can see, I'm passing the item dialog pointer into the yes/no dialog so it could close it, but the line just doesn't work..

Everything is running correctly on the debugger, when I reach to the line:

```
item_alert.dismiss();
```

it is pointed correctly to the item dialog, but this command just won't close it..
I tried the `.close();` command also but same thing, nothing happens.

What am I missing?
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

`builder.show();`

instead of

`item_alert.show();`

Comment: set all title, setPositiveButton, setNegativeButton, message then call **builder.create();** which will return AlertDialog object which you can show/dismiss but remember you cant manipulate a builder after **builder.create()** is called

Comment: Oh nice, I got it right this time! I needed to combine the answer with your previous one creating class object.. Thank you so much!! I was struggling with this for few days!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer thanks to Nishant Paradamwar:

```
public class Popup{
    AlertDialog item_alert; // *creating class object of it*

    private void popupItem(final int item_id) {

            //setup popup window
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Holo_Light_ButtonBar_AlertDialog));

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_popup_item_alert, null);

            builder.setView(dialoglayout);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.edit_item));




            //setup delete button
            final ImageButton deleteImageButton = (ImageButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.template_popup_item_delete);
            deleteImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickDeleteItem(item_id); // *removed 2nd argument*
                }
            });

            item_alert = builder.create(); // *moved the create to bottom so it will contain all parts*
            item_alert.show(); // *calling the alert not builder*

        }

        private void clickDeleteItem(final int item_id) { // *removed second argument, its in class now*
            // create (another) popup delete for "are you sure? yes/no"
            AlertDialog.Builder alert_yesno = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            alert_yesno.setTitle(getString(R.string.want_to_remove));

            alert_yesno.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    // ... deleting the item(id)..

                    item_alert.dismiss(); // close the previous popup dialog //~~ *WORKING NOW!

                }
            });

            alert_yesno.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });

            alert_yesno.show();
        }
}
```